# HTML5 input number min max not working with required

Tags: css, html

I would like to force the user to type their age. I also would like to make sure they only enter between 18-99. Is that possible with `HTML5` attributes like `required`, `pattern`, `min` and `max`? Seems like it is not working

```
<form>
    <input type="number" name="Q2age" id="Q2age" size="10" min="18" max="99" pattern="[1-8][0-9]" required>
    <button type="submit" class="button" id="test">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Am I doing something wrong here? I use Firefox 22.0 on Ubuntu 12.0.4LTS (tested on Chrome as well, but doesn't work.) Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the expected behaviour because FF21 doesnt supports min,max attribute...

you can check it in http://html5test.com/

Check the screenshot
[image]

Comment: Thank you, @ArunBertil. I think you are right. I'll start checking html5test site you mentioned above before asking hasty questions like this in the future. :)

Answer (score 3):

Your code works fine.  Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KLxLx/) (I'm using latest chrome)

My only concern you is your `pattern="[1-8][0-9]"` can simple use this

```
pattern="[0-9]{2}"
```

Comment: Thank you for your help @user1671639. But I would like my code to work across all browsers. Seems like The answer is that Firefox 21 doesn't support this feature. :) Btw, the pattern is to make sure user doesn't enter "1" as the first digit. If you have a more elegant way to write it in regex, I'd love to learn. :)

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't work in Firefox but it works in Chrome, Internet Explorer, Safari and Opera.

Please find the working demo here: [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pcgy3/1/)

```
<form action="">

<input type="number" name="points" min="1" max="10" name="Q2age" id="Q2age" required>

 <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: thank you for the explanation and taking time to create the demo. You're right. It doesn't work in Firefox so I'll use an alternative method of validating in jQuery. :)

Comment: Your example input has two `name` attributes.