# html - minimum password length

Tags: html, forms

I'm trying to make the user input a password length of minimum 6 characters.
Right now it just wants a single character but I cannot understand, why it does not require a minimum of 6 chars, when I have specified the minimum length.

I studied w3school's page about input types, including the "min" input restriction. I implemented it but it's still not working.

What is wrong with this?

```
<div class="form"> 
   <input type="password"
   min="123456"
   step="1"
   class="form-control"
   placeholder="Password"
   name="user_pass"
   required
</div>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17872928/html5-input-number-min-max-not-working-with-required

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10281962/is-there-a-minlength-validation-attribute-in-html5

Comment: according to html5test.com, my browser do support the "min" attribute.

@RickHitchcock, that solution worked. Thanks.