# HTML5 only set minimum characters for input type number

Tags: html, cordova

I have this two inputs one of type text and the other number

```
<input type="number" class="form-control" id="phone" name="phone" placeholder="Telephone Number"  maxlength="10" pattern=".{10,}" required title="10 characters minimum"/>


<input type="text" class="form-control" id="names" name="names" placeholder="Names" pattern=".{5,30}" title="Minimum of 5 characters required"/>
```

the input text is able to respond when the user fills less than 5 characters but the type number does not respond when the input is less or greater than 10. It does respond however to the required rule.

How can i set the minimum characters for the input type number without having to result to javascript?.

Comment: Max in input type number define max number .not length of that number

Comment: @HimeshSuthar I have found that but its the minimum length when input is number that is problematic.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML5 input number min max not working with required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17872928/html5-input-number-min-max-not-working-with-required)

Comment: @thepio I am looking to accept a mimimum of ten numeric characters.

Comment: Use input type= text and put this regex . min digits 10 and max 15 pattern="\d{10,15}"

Comment: Really people, whoever marked this as duplicate ought to read the question tagged.

Comment: @HimeshSuthar That does not work on cordova.

Comment: Man u can compare it in using javascript. Fetch the value of this input and compare it with str.match(&quot;\d{10,15}&quot;). If its true thn valid

Comment: @HimeshSuthar I know i can solve it in javascript but i dont want to use javascript for now. Thanks for the suggestions though.

Comment: https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19066674/why-is-input-pattern-attribute-not-working-for-numerics&ved=0ahUKEwi8lv7AstnUAhVBKY8KHTdNBssQFggfMAA&usg=AFQjCNF_tRneM8gkSySg87sm2HEJsOOvSA.   Refer this

Comment: @HimeshSuthar Its a long standing unsolved bug in cordova, no need of trying. problem can only be solved using javascript.

Comment: @jsjsjsjsjsjs there in my linked answer there is both pattern and min + max explained. Only thing I would add is a link to this site http://caniuse.com/ where you can see the browser support for stuff.

Comment: Really dude! Really!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could solve it with the `min` attribute of the input type `number` like `min="1000000000"`.