# Angularjs Input restriction

Tags: html, angularjs, forms, input

I have an input box in a form and I want user to enter number only and maxlength of the number should be 10.

```
<input type="text" maxlength="10" ng-model="phoneNumber" class="form-control"/>
```

When I use the method above, I can restrict the user with 10 digit but user can enter letter.

```
<input type="number" ng-model="phoneNumber" class="form-control"/>
```

When I use the second method, user can only enter numbers but I cannot restrict to enter only 10 digits.

Instead of warning the user, is there any other option by which I can combine these two attribute?

Comment: It's best to do any validations in the back-end (the user is always in control of the front-end)

Comment: As a rule of thumb, do data validation in terms of user experience on the front-end, and data validation in terms of security on the back end. Both layers involve validation, but different types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Actually input `type=number` only handles and not allows user to submit the form if the entered number is not in range.

**Please refer:**

[How can I limit possible inputs in a HTML5 "number" element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8354975/how-can-i-limit-possible-inputs-in-a-html5-number-element)

**More details:**

[maxlength ignored for input type="number" in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18510845/maxlength-ignored-for-input-type-number-in-chrome)

[HTML5 input number min max not working with required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17872928/html5-input-number-min-max-not-working-with-required)

Comment: OP asked to allow only 10 digit long numbers to be entered. With `max="99999"` (or `ng-maxlength="10"`) you can type as many as you like (_even though it's not validated_).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18510845/maxlength-ignored-for-input-type-number-in-chrome

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18510845/maxlength-ignored-for-input-type-number-in-chrome looks like this one works for me. Thanks!